# Can I get distinct values of a field with only the latest date in the Aggregation framework?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection full of taxi data which looks something like this (simplified):

```
{
     "TaxiLicense" : "TET123",
     "GetOff" : "2015-01-10,00:02:11",
     "GetOffLongitude" : 121.41
}
```

Since this real time data, the Taxi is constantly sending new documents to the collection with a new GetOff time along with GPS coordinates. I only want the GPS coordinates for each distinct Taxi License at the most recent GetOff time.

Is there a way for the Aggregation Framework to do this in Java or do I need to aggregate all the entries and then have my Java program find the latest time for each unique taxi?

I'm currently working with

```
DBObject taxigroup = new BasicDBObject("$group",
                               new BasicDBObject("_id", 
                                   new BasicDBObject("License","$TaxiLicense")
                                   .append("getoff","$GetOff").append("longitude","GetOffLongitude"))
                               );
AggregationOutput aggout = taxistationOfCollection.aggregate( Arrays.asList(taxigroup));
```

Comment: I see you are trying to edit the answer. The "_id" key of `$group` does not need to be an object but can be a string representing the variable value of a field. It's not a compound object so there is no benefit in compounding the key as an object for a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically looking for the [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operator. This is commonly used with [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and it returns the "last" document properties found at the grouping boundary.

Basic pipeline:

```
[
    { "$sort": { "TaxiLicence": 1, "GetOff": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$TaxiLicence",
       "GetOff": { "$last": "$GetOff" },
       "GetOffLongitude": { "$last": "$GetOffLongitude" }
    }}
]
```

Or specifically to construct with the Java Driver:

```
  DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort",
      new BasicDBObject("TaxiLicence", 1)
          .append("GetOff",1)
  );

  DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",
      new BasicDBObject("_id", "$TaxiLicence"
          .append("GetOff", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$GetOff" ) )
          .append("GeOffLongitude", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$GeOffLongitude" ))
  );

  AggregationOutput aggout = taxistationOfCollection.aggregate(sort,group);
```